# What happens to MongoDB fields which have no corresponding definition in Morphia?

Tags: java, morphia

I have a project which combines Python's MongoEngine and Java's Morphia.

The Python part is used for the frontend and it uses MongoEngine for document modeling. It stores a lot of information and the frontend is often changing so I will have to add or subtract new fields frequently.

The Java part does some computation task and it relies only on a few fields in the model. To map each field from MongoEngine to Java's Morphia models can be tedious since I won't be using them anyways in the Java part.

*In the Morphia model, I only want to declare variables/fields which I am going to use.*
So what happens if I don't declare the corresponding variables for the mongo document fields in morphia? 
Will the original document written by the python part with much more fields be overwritten by Morphia?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to be careful: a simple `.save()` will replace the document with your partial data — all the fields, which you haven't mapped in Morphia will be gone.

What you want to use is a [partial update](https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.4/guides/updating/). For example the [`.set()`](https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.4/javadoc/?org/mongodb/morphia/query/UpdateOperations.html)  operation is being translated to a [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) in MongoDB — this will only change the field you have specified and this is what you want.

I'm not sure if this is really a great solution. I'd also consider either mapping the entire entity or avoiding Morphia altogether; you are only using a very small subset of the Object Document Mapper and could probably achieve the same with the plain Java client with less confusion (and it's also much better maintained).

Comment: This is correct. Since Morphia doesn't do any class definition changes, it just can't track any fields that aren't explicitly defined.